# Is it possible in php to turn string var into type name?

Tags: php, string, types

So, can I get this code working:

```
    $typename='integer';
    $tmp='12321321312';
    $var=($typename)$tmp;
```

**WITHOUT** using conditions, like:

```
    if($typename=='integer')
        $var=(integer) $tmp;
```

**AND WITHOUT** using evals, like:

```
   eval( '$var=(' . $typename . ') $tmp;' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`settype`](https://www.php.net/settype).

```
$typename = 'integer';
$tmp = '12321321312'; // $tmp will be passed as a reference
settype($tmp, $typename);

// $tmp is now an integer
```

Possibles values of type are:

- "boolean" (or, since PHP 4.2.0, "bool")
- "integer" (or, since PHP 4.2.0, "int")
- "float" (only possible since PHP 4.2.0, for older versions use the deprecated variant "double")
- "string"
- "array"
- "object"
- "null" (since PHP 4.2.0)

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. To my shame I was unable to make up a correct search query to find this function.

Comment: That's great! You're welcome. I would've searched something like "dynamic type casting".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (available on PHP versions => 5.3.0).

```
$typename = 'intval';
$tmp = '2323';
$var = $typename($tmp); // <= note the syntax difference
var_dump($var);
```

Output:

```
int(2323)
```

Comment: Great solution, however (IMHO) settype() is far more convenient, because the name of function tells what it does. Clear code == good code.